# Problem with running headers, custom class

Tags: header-footer

I'm having a problem with headers.  So I'm typesetting my dissertation using the `uclathes` class (provided, [here](https://github.com/jolohaga/uclathes) – I wish they had official support for that but they don't ...)
and I can't get running headers to work. This:

```
\documentclass{uclathes} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

gives me an `Undefined control sequence. \@oddhead -> hbox {}\slshape \rightmark \hfil \rm \thepage`  error.

In the `*.cls` file I find the following definitions:

```
\mark{{}{}}

\def\ps@headings{\def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenfoot{}%     No feet.
\def\@oddhead{\hbox {}\slshape \rightmark \hfil \rm\thepage}% Heading.
\def\chaptermark##1{\markright {\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}}}}

\def\ps@myheadings{\def\@oddhead{\hbox{}\slshape\rightmark \hfil \rm\thepage}%
\def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenhead{\rm \thepage\hfil\slshape\leftmark\hbox {}}%
\def\@evenfoot{}\def\sectionmark##1{}\def\subsectionmark##1{}}
```

Can anyone spot any error here?  Or has a suggestion what else might be wrong?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `\rm`. That is no longer supported in LaTeX. Change to `\normalfont\textrm{\thepage}` (4 times, of which one in a comment).

```
% \def\ps@plain{\def\@oddhead{}
%   \def\@oddfoot{\hfil\normalfont\textrm{\thepage}\hfil}
%   \def\@evenhead{}
%   \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}

% Definition of 'headings' page style 
%  Note the use of ##1 for parameter of \def\chaptermark inside the
%  \def\ps@headings.
%

\def\ps@headings{\def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenfoot{}%     No feet.
\def\@oddhead{\hbox {}\slshape \rightmark \hfil \normalfont\textrm{\thepage}}% Heading.
\def\chaptermark##1{\markright {\uppercase{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}}}}

% Definition of 'myheadings' page style.  
%
\def\ps@myheadings{\def\@oddhead{\hbox{}\slshape\rightmark \hfil \normalfont\textrm{\thepage}}%
\def\@oddfoot{}\def\@evenhead{\normalfont\textrm{\thepage}\hfil\slshape\leftmark\hbox {}}%
\def\@evenfoot{}\def\sectionmark##1{}\def\subsectionmark##1{}}
```

Comment: just a minor comment, the status of `\rm` in latex hasn't changed since 1993, so it's not a recent change:-).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The problem with that package is that the university doesn't provide official LaTeX support (shame on them) and it's been modified and patched by random people in the meanwhile to respond to changes in the formatting ... so no suprise there are inconsistencies.

Comment: Actually, just replacing `\rm' with `\normalfont` would have been enough.

Answer (score 2):

This makes the error go away. I also tweaked some of the settings to prevent the page numbers from overlapping the text:

```
\documentclass{uclathes}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-20pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{10pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{10pt}
\DeclareOldFontCommand{\rm}{\normalfont\rmfamily}{\mathrm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does look awful, indeed.  I need to redo the margin settings.

Comment: Oh, I see you just edited it.  That's helpful, thank you!   I think I'll change the values in the *.cls itself though.